# Apache on debian don't redirect http to https correctly

Tags: debian, mod-rewrite, apache2, debian-bullseye

Debian 11

config file: **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    ServerName zabbix.example.ru

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName zabbix.example.ru
    DocumentRoot "/usr/share/zabbix/"
</VirtualHost>
```

If I open in brouser zabbix.example.ru it will be open by https. But if I open manualy http://zabbix.example.ru it doesn't redirect to https

The same setting (as I understand) perfectly forks for me on FreeBSD, but it looks like on Debian I should make something other

**/usr/sbin/apachectl -S**

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   zabbix.lasil.ru (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
*:443                  zabbix.lasil.ru (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:9)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

**UPD**: I was a little wrong about problem. Not only there is no redirect, but such an error is also issued

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) Server at zabbix.example.ru Port 80
```

Comment: For your update, your Virtual Host for port 443 does not have an SSL certificate configured. Therefore it is speaking HTTP and not HTTPS.

Comment: Or, they have seemingly enabled SSL on port 80?! @JohnHanley

Comment: Port 80 does not have HTTPS enabled. If it was enabled, the error message would be different.

Comment: @JohnHanley "You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port." - Only HTTP (port 80) requests get this message (server rejects the request and the redirect does not happen). HTTPS (port 443) requests appear to be working just fine (there is a valid SSL cert).

Comment: @MrWhite - Oops,  I read the port numbers backwards. How is SSL enabled on port 80? The VirtualHost does not show that configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's to all.

After reading comments I understand that site configuration (where was enabled SSL) (that was in **/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/** folder) wasn't limited to any VirtualHost, so it was enabled to **all** server, not only to port 443

I moved it to VirtualHost on port 433 and problem was solved

Comment: Apache doesn't are about *where* the *file* is located. It cares about in what type of config it's located. Apache has different sections with different scopes, e.g. vhost, directory, serverwide etc.

Answer (score 2):

You want a permanent, unconditional redirect. Simply don't use mod_rewrite:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zabbix.example.ru
    Redirect permanent / https://zabbix.example.ru/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I still got error. By the way I see I didn't mention an important thing, please see question update

Comment: Have you included *ALL* of your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` in the question?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to disable 000-default site.

```
# a2dissite 000-default
# systemctl reload apache2
```

Cheers!